# Issue in adding third party dependency in Maven during Jenkins build - ODM

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, odm, ibm-odm

I am trying to build ODM projects outside of eclipse using the Jenkins pipeline and Maven plugin. I am following the link : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSQP76_8.9.0/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.designer.run/build_topics/con_buildcmd_intro.html
Though this link works well without the Jenkins pipeline in my local(Windows), but when I try to run the same setup in Jenkins(Linux machine), I am getting the following error :

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.ibm.rules.buildcommand:rules-compiler-maven-plugin:jar:8.10.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ helloWorld:hello-xom:[unknown-version], /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/odm-devops-build/Hello XOM/pom.xml, line 19, column 21
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.ibm.rules.buildcommand:rules-compiler-maven-plugin:8.10.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.ibm.rules.buildcommand:rules-compiler-maven-plugin:jar:8.10.0.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @ 
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: decisionservice @ helloWorld:hello-main:[unknown-version], /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/odm-devops-build/Hello Main Service/pom.xml, line 14, column 16
```

The pom file which is referred in the above error is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>helloWorld</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>hello-main</artifactId>
    <packaging>decisionservice</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.ibm.rules.buildcommand</groupId>
                <artifactId>rules-compiler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>

                    <deployments>
                        <deployment>
                            <name>simple dep</name>
                        </deployment>
                    </deployments>

                    <resolvers>
                        <resolver>
              <!-- The values of the kind and url of the project correspond to the 'kind' and 'url' attribute values of an 'entries' element in the .ruleproject file. -->
                            <kind>JAVA_PROJECT</kind>
                            <url>platform:/Hello XOM</url>
              <!-- The artifactKey references the groupId and artifactId of a Maven dependency. -->
                            <artifactKey>${project.groupId}:hello-xom</artifactKey>
                        </resolver>
                    </resolvers>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>hello-xom</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Please let me know if anyone has faced a similar issue or has a possible resolution to the above issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Possible resolution: "install the Build Command Maven plugin and its related Operational Decision Manager artifacts in your Maven repository" ... "on each machine that contains build agents"

> To deploy the Build Command Maven plugin to a *remote* Maven repository, you must configure Maven in your environment. You then use the following command: mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=rules-compiler-maven-plugin.jar -DpomFile=rules-compiler-maven-plugin.pom

This requires access to the Jenkins / Maven server, and at many companies would be done by DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

You install the Build Command Maven plugin and its related Operational Decision Manager artifacts in your Maven repository.

## Deploying the Build Command plugin

You deploy the plugin only once on each machine that contains build agents.

To deploy the Build Command Maven plugin to a remote Maven repository, you must first configure Maven in your environment.

Then, in `<InstallDir>/buildcommand/rules-compiler`, open a command prompt.
Use the following command:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=rules-compiler.jar -DpomFile=rules-compiler-maven-plugin.pom
```

If you do not have a remote repository, you can test the plugin locally. You run the following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=rules-compiler.jar -DpomFile=rules-compiler-maven-plugin.pom
```

This command adds the following plugin in your local Maven repository:

```
com/ibm/rules/buildcommand/rules-compiler
```

## Deploying the annotations archive

If you want to build COBOL projects or projects that use XOM annotations, you must also deploy the annotations archive to your environment before you can build the projects.

In `<InstallDir>/buildcommand/rules-compiler`, open a command prompt.
Use the following command:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=rules-compiler.jar -DpomFile=xom-annotations.pom
```

If you do not have a remote repository, you can test the plugin locally. You run the following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=rules-compiler.jar -DpomFile=xom-annotations.pom
```

This command adds the following plugin in your local Maven repository:

```
com/ibm/rules/buildcommand/xom-annotation
```

[Source](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP76_8.10.x/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.designer.run/build_topics/con_buildcmd_prep_env.html)